# Codeigniter query->num_rows Returning 0 Incorrectly

Tags: php, codeigniter

I cannot seem to get the below query to run and return `num_rows` correctly. No matter what happens, `$query->num_rows > 0` always returns `false` even when I expect it to return `true`. Any ideas?

```
    $post_id = $this->input->post('post_id');
    $poster_id = $this->input->post('poster_id');
    $my_id = $this->session->userdata('id');

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM default_post_likes
                               WHERE liker_id = '$my_id'
                               AND post_id = '$post_id'");

    if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
        echo json_encode(array('error' => 'e1'));
    } else {
        $data = array(
            'poster_id' => $poster_id,
            'post_id' => $post_id,
            'liker_id' => $my_id
        );

        $this->db->insert('default_post_likes', $data);

        echo json_encode(array('success' => true));
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$query->num_rows` should be a function `$query->num_rows()`

Comment: I'm surprised that worked, I am pretty sure there is a variable `num_rows` to the query object.

Comment: I'm sure it is, but for some reason, it's returning `0` which is wrong in this case. It may be a buggy driver. My guess is `sqlsrv`. I think I had that issue before as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here, problem lies

```
if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
    echo json_encode(array('error' => 'e1'));
}

$query->num_rows  (Wrong)
```

should be a function and hence you have to use it as

```
$query->num_rows() (Right)
```

Thats why it is returning False